# Why does long integer take more than 4 bytes on some systems?

Tags: c++, long-integer

I understand that the standard says that the size of a `long integer` is implementation dependant, but I am not sure why.

All it needs to do is to be able to store -2147483647 to 2147483647 or 0 to 4294967295.

Assuming that 1 byte is 8 bits, this should never need more than 4 bytes. Is it safe to say, then, that a long integer will take more than 4 bytes only if a byte has less than 8 bits? Or could there be other possibilities as well? Like maybe inefficient implementations wasting space?

Comment: Some people like to have longer integers.  They can be very handy at times.  (The history of the various integer sizes in C is quite convoluted.)

Comment: Yet it might be sometimes faster to compute on larger entities. AFAIK original Itanium and Alpha

Comment: A `byte` can have as many bits as it wants. I believe the lower limit was `7` in **C++03** and `8` in **C++11**. Every integral type can have as many bits as it wants, it only has to satisfy certain guarantees of lower bounds and relations to other integral types.

Comment: @K-ballo: The minimum size of a char in C++ and C has been 8 bits, going back to the original (1989) standard for C.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Isn't it theoretically `7`, since that's all it takes to represent the characters understood by the language? **C++11** explicitly says that a `char` has to have enough bits to represent `UTF8`.

Comment: @K-ballo: C89 and C++98 both specifically require that UCHAR_MAX/std::limits<unsigned char>::max be at least 256 (and that signed char cover (at least) -127..127.

Comment: Probably because the situation on 32-bit systems, where `int` and `long` are the same size, is a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra bytes aren't a waste of space. A larger range is quite useful. The standard specifies *minimum* ranges, not the precise range itself; there's nothing wrong with having wider types.

When the standard originally specified an `int` should be at least 16 bits, common processors had registers no larger than that. Representing a `long` took two registers and special operations!

But then 32 bits became the norm, and now `int`s are 32 bits everywhere and `long`s are 64. Nowadays most processors have 64-bit instructions, and a `long` can often be stored in a single register.

Comment: `long long` is 64-bit, at least on 32-bit compiler on 32-bit system. Never heard about 128-bit. Do you have any link for that?

Comment: @nhahtdh -- I was totally wrong. A little Googling shows that 128-bit `long long` was killed by the C99 committee. I have removed the whole sentence from my post.

Comment: Another thing: `long` is not always 64-bit. It can be 32-bit, actually.

Comment: @nhahtdh there's [__int128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) on gcc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int128

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It is GNU C extension (which means you can only use it if you use gcc as your compiler). It is not part of the C standard.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, just to provide you a link. This post isn't related to portability

Answer (score 2):

An obvious use for a `long` larger than 32 bits is to have a larger range available.

For example, before `long long int` (and company) were in the standard, DEC was selling 64-bit (Alpha) processors and a 64-bit operating system. They built a (conforming) system with:

```
char = 1 byte
short = 2 bytes
int = 4 bytes
long = 8 bytes
```

As to why they'd do this: well, an obvious reason was so their customers would have access to a 64-bit type and take advantage of their 64-bit hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming quite a few things:

- A byte is `CHAR_BIT` bits wide

The PDP-10 had bytes ranging from 1 to 36 bits. The DEC VAX supported operations on 128-bit integer types. So, there's plenty reason to go over and above what the standard mandates.

- The limits for data types are given in §3.9.1/8

> Specializations of the standard template std::numeric_limits (18.3)
>   shall specify the maximum and minimum values of each arithmetic type
>   for an implementation.

Lookup `<limits>` header.

[This](http://www.bandwidthco.com/whitepapers/programming/c-c++/Integer%20Types%20in%20C%20and%20C++.pdf) article by Jack Klein may be of interest to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an integer of a specific size, then you want to use the types with the size specified:

int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
int128_t
...

These are available in some random header file (it varies depending on the OS you're using, although in C++ it seems to be <stdint>)

You have the unsigned version using a u at the beginning (uint32_t).

The others already answered why the size would be so and so.

Note that the newest Intel processors support numbers of 256 bits too. What a waste, hey?! 8-)

Oh! And time_t is starting to use 64 bits too. In 2068, time_t in 32 bits will go negative and give you a date in late 1800... That's a good reason to adopt 64 bits for a few things.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for using an 8 byte integer is to be able to address more than 4 gigs of memory.  Ie. 2^32 = 4 gigabytes.  2^64 = well, it's a lot!

Personally, I've used 8 byte ints for implementing a radix sort on double floats (casting the floats as ints then doing magical things with it that aren't worth describing here. :))